# How to programmatically decompose an EF Core include clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, iqueryable

My EF Core application uses a design pattern that aims to support flexible entity queries, by allowing navigation property loading to be specified at runtime. There are 3 key elements to this pattern:

1. Declare a delegate that represents an EF Core include expression

```
public delegate IIncludableQueryable<T, object> IncludeClause<T>(IQueryable<T> value);
```

2. Create pre-defined instances of this delegate that represent include expressions for various scenarios:

```
public static IncludeClause<Blog> BlogFull => entities =>
    entities
        .Include(e => e.Author)
        .Include(e => e.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Comments);
```

3. Create entity query methods that adjust their property loading behaviour according to the passed include clause:

```
public async Task<Blog> GetBlog(int id, IncludeClause<Blog> include)
{
    return await include(_context.Set<Blog>()).FirstAsync(blog => blog.Id == id);
}
```

The above pattern works well, but now I am looking for a way to programmatically decompose any predefined include clause, to determine the set of entity types that it references.

In the above example, I would expect the result of this decomposition to be an array of types, like this:

```
new[] { typeof(Blog), typeof(Author), typeof(Post), typeof(Comment), }
```

Can anyone please suggest how to parse the above `BlogFull` expression tree to determine the entity types that it references?

**Update**

As requested by Ivan Stoev, I'll try to provide more details of my actual goal.

Database queries are commonly used to populate web API response models, each of which may include a hierarchy of nested models that broadly match the schema of the entity model. So, a deep entity query, like the one above, can result in a deeply-populated API response.

The response model implementation already gracefully ignores unpopulated entity navigation properties, but it breaks JSON serialization when there is a circular reference in the entity data. For example, if the `Post` entity type has a parent `Blog` navigation property, the resulting API response model will contain a circular reference that JSON serialization cannot handle.

My intended solution to this problem is to use the EF Core include clause as the basis of a tracking list that determines which nested types any response model should include. The root-level response model receives the full list from the API controller, and removes its own entity type from that list, before passing it on to nested response models.

So, in the above example, the API controller generates a list of 4 types (`Blog`, `Author`, `Post`, `Comment`) and passes this to `BlogResponseModel`. `BlogResponseModel` truncates the list and passes 3 types (`Author`, `Post`, `Comment`) to `AuthorResponseModel` and `PostResponseModel`. And since the `Blog` type is not passed to `PostResponseModel`, it will not attempt to populate its own `Blog` property, despite its own source `Post` entity having this property populated.

If there's a simpler way of achieving this goal, with the same level of flexibility, I will be keen to hear about it.

Comment: Elements of the include *path* are *not* types, but *navigations*, so the result cannot by array of type. For instance, the string representation of your sample include path is "Blog.Author" and "Blog.Posts.Comments" (note the `Posts` - it is collection property of `Blog`, not a `Post` type). Also you can have multiple navigations from EntityA type to EntityB type via different reference and/or collection navigation properties. Please provide more details for what you are trying to achieve, the expression of course is parseable, just need to know what to get from there.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - it makes sense. As requested, I have updated the question to include more details of my goal and I am open to any approach that achieves this goal.

Comment: Thank you. What are you describing is actually a responsibility of the serializer, since EFC have no issues with circular references. Also you probably know that the lack of Include does not prevent loading a reference/collection navigation property in case of tracking queries. So the only reliable solution is to use projection (`Select`) query populating directly dto/view/response models, excluding their "inverse" properties. Your approach may work in simplified parent -> children -> grandchildren, but will fail with inverse collections (e.g. `Author.Blogs`) or multiple relations.

Comment: So you really need some sort of a exclude inverse (curcular) properties of object "navigations", depending of the query object graph. e.g. when loading `Author.Blogs`, exclude `Blog.Author`. But when loading `Blog.Author`, exclude `Author,Blogs`. Basically *property" exclusion filter. Or utilize reference loop handling of JSON serializers as explained in the [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization) topic in the official EFC docs.

Comment: Thanks again @IvanStoev. After reflecting on your comments, I realize I need to think more carefully about this challenge and devise a pattern that properly addresses all the edge cases.